# How to check if particular Docker image exists on IBM container registry

Tags: docker

I want to check if the image with name $image:$tag exists on IBM container registry. How Can I do it using bash command?

Answer (score 0):

You can use registry API

```
curl http://example.registry:5000/v2/"IMAGE NAME"/tags/list | grep "TAG"
```

and check if string is empty

Comment: I am checking in ibm container registry